# How to SUM rows values according to another rows which contains same values?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sum

I am trying to get `number of gusts` based on a `date`
User could be able to search `number of guests` for a date by entering a `date`

my form is:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" class="booking_reference">
    <input type="text" placeholder="date" required name="search_text">
    <span class="arrow">
        <input type="submit" value="CHECK" name="search" class="search_button">
    </span>
</form>
```

And my action section is :

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
$serch_text = $_POST["search_text"]; 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","guest");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }       
    $searching_date = $serch_text;
    $searchroute = "select * from guest_tbl where date = '$searching_date'";
    $result = $con->query($searchroute);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ($row == 0) { echo '<div style="color: red;">No one found for the date: <b>' . $serch_text . '</b>. Please refine your date</div>' ; 
    } else {        
        echo '<h3>Total guest for the day : '. $serch_text .'</h3>';        
        $total_guests = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT date SUM(nmbr_of_guests) FROM guest WHERE date = "'.$serch_text.'"'); // selecting and summing the value of all the 'nmbr_of_guests' rows in same date - $serch_text     
        echo $total_guests;
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
}
```

I have following rows in my database:

[image: Database]

Expecting results is:

1. if I enter **2015-06-30** in the search field `$echo $total_guests`
   should echo **5** - (because of 2+3)
2. if I enter **2015-06-25** in the search field `$echo $total_guests`
   should echo **6** - (because of `nmbr_of_guests` column have just 6 for
   the date)
3. if I enter **Any other date** in the search field, it should echo **No
   one found for the date: **Any other date**. Please refine
   your date.**

**3rd is fine** I am getting that text in red line when the date is not found.

But when I enter **2015-06-30** or **2015-06-25** I am getting just blank.
That means `$total_guests;` returns nothing / blank.

how can make it that `$total_guests;` show the SUM of `nmbr_of_guests` rows values for the date (5 or 6 in this case) ??

---

Note: it's an old site. I will replace all the **MySQLi** to **PDO** when I finish this. It is big file and it will take time to replace all the lines where found MySQLi.

Comment: Mysqli is fair. You must be talking about `mysql_` functions that are deprecated. But you should protect your script againts sql injections

Comment: Are you sure your query is working. I think it had some error over here `date SUM(nmbr_of_guests)`

Comment: Hi, What output do u got ?

Comment: @KarthikKeyan if I search for a date that is **not** in the database: http://i58.tinypic.com/1zmnpl4.jpg AND If I put **2015-06-30** I am getting this: http://i61.tinypic.com/2ro446w.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comma is missing from date and sum...query should be-

```
 $total_guests = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT date, SUM(nmbr_of_guests) FROM guest WHERE date = "'.$serch_text.'"'); // selecting and summing the value of all the 'nmbr_of_guests' rows in same date - $serch_text
```

**Update**

Your code-

```
echo '<h3>Total guest for the day : '. $serch_text .'</h3>';        
        $total_guests = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT date SUM(nmbr_of_guests) FROM guest WHERE date = "'.$serch_text.'"'); // selecting and summing the value of all the 'nmbr_of_guests' rows in same date - $serch_text     
        echo $total_guests;
        mysqli_close($con);
```

Try to check as per below-

```
    $total_guests = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT SUM(nmbr_of_guests) FROM guest WHERE date = "'.$serch_text.'"'); // selecting and summing the value of all the 'nmbr_of_guests' rows in same date - $serch_text     

echo '<h3>Total guest for the date of '. $serch_text .' are '.$total_guests.'</h3>';        
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: [It seems to be my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021825/how-to-sum-rows-values-according-to-another-rows-which-contains-same-values#comment50068791_31021825)

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try like this

```
 $total_guests = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT date,nmbr_of_guests FROM guest_tbl WHERE date = "'.$serch_text.'"');
```

Assign the one variable "0" and count the value

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($total_guests as $guests){
$total = $total + $guests->nmbr_of_guests;
}
echo $total;
```

Comment: I found the issue.. it was wrong `table` name.. table name is `guest_tbl` NOT `guest`. Anyhow after I change the table name correctly now I am getting this **Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\guest\index.php on line 24**
Line 24 is `echo $total_guests;` After I use your code also same.. it means both of our SUMMING code is fine.. but still there is another issue..

Comment: Could you pls check it now

Comment: After I added your updated code I am getting this [Link](http://i58.tinypic.com/x1lj5u.jpg)